# Unable to load raster image in QGIS 3.20 Print composer

Tags: print-composer, image, printing

I have loaded QGIS 3.20, and in print composer, I have tried to load a gif image I have used a lot in other versions, and it fails to load,  just the red X through the box. I have checked 3.18 settings vs 3.20 settings in print composer and seem to be the same.

Comment: Did you try saving project with image in 3.18 and than open it in 3.20? What is the result?

Comment: Yes, saving in 3.18 and then opening in 3.20 works,

Comment: OK, so than this could be a workaround. However, can you post a screenshot of what you do when import fails in QGIS 3.20? Maybe also provide the raster you try to load?

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a 3.20 bug.

Comment: I can confirm your finding: loading the same GIF in print composer works perfect in 3.18, but not in 3.20. So probably indeed a bug, you should report it: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Workaround: click the image, then choose svg and then choose raster again. It should appear after that.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and solve them with pick and drop the image.